# Auto Scale-UP Azure VM without Downtime

Tags: azure-vm

I know that we can use Azure Automation to be triggered by azure alerts to auto-SCALE UP , but then it causes around 20 to 30 mins downtime.

**Is it possible to Auto-Scale UP Azure VM, without downtime ?**

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we are using azure VMSS , then when it auto scales out, there is no downtime.
In case of azure VM, when it auto scales up or auto scales down to the next size, there will be some downtime.